# Suma de arreglos en JS

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo

```
let arreglo = [["Enero", 1], ["Febrero", 2], ["Marzo", 3]];
```

Quiero sumar por cada el elemento del arreglo el indice [1] con el indice [1].

Quiero obtener :

```
let arregloObtenido =  [["Enero", 1], ["Febrero", 3], ["Marzo", 6]];
```

Comment: podrías añadir el código de lo que haz intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arreglo  = [["Enero", 1], ["Febrero", 2], ["Marzo", 3]];
let arregloObtenido = [];
let suma = 0;
arreglo.forEach(function (elemento, indice, array) {
 suma+=elemento[1];
 arregloObtenido.push([elemento[0],suma]);
});
  
document.write(arregloObtenido);
```

Comment: ok, ya lo actualize, vuelveme a calificar :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let arreglo = [["Enero", 1], ["Febrero", 2], ["Marzo", 3]];

let arregloObtenido = []
let cont = 0;
arreglo.forEach((item) => {
    let val = item[1];
    if (arreglo[cont-1]) {
        val += arreglo[cont-1][1]
    }
    item[1] = val
    arregloObtenido.push(item)
    cont++;
})

console.log(arregloObtenido)
```